# combining words in tm R is not achieving desired result

Tags: r, tm, corpus, qdap

I am trying to combine a few words so that they count as one.
In this example I want `val` and `valuatin` to be counted as `valuation`.

The code I have been using to try and do this is below:

```
#load in package
library(tm)

replaceWords <- function(x, from, keep){
  regex_pat <- paste(from, collapse = "|")
  gsub(regex_pat, keep, x)
}


oldwords <- c("val", "valuati")
newword  <- c("valuation")

TextDoc2 <- tm_map(TextDoc, replaceWords, from=oldwords, keep=newword)
```

However this does not work as expected. Any time there is `val` in a word it is now being replaced with `valuation`. For example `equivalent` becomes `equivaluation`. How do I get around this error and achieved my desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this function -

```
replaceWords <- function(x, from, keep){
  regex_pat <- sprintf('\\b(%s)\\b', paste(from, collapse = '|'))
  gsub(regex_pat, keep, x)
}
```

`val` matches with `equivalent`. Adding word boundaries stop that from happening.

```
grepl('val', 'equivalent')
#[1] TRUE
grepl('\\bval\\b', 'equivalent')
#[1] FALSE
```